# delete every nth item in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

Trying to delete every nth item in scheme recursively

```
    (define x '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 15 10))

    (define ndelete
        (lambda (alist nth) ;@params (list to delete items from) (nth intervals to delete items)
            (cond [(null? alist) alist] ;if null, return empty list
                [(if (= nth 1) (ndelete (cdr alist) nth))]
                [else (list (car alist) (ndelete (cdr alist) (- nth 1)))]
    )))
```

when i call:

```
    > (ndelete x 5)
```

the output should be:

> (1 2 3 4 6 7 8 15)

but i get blank output:

```
    > (ndelete x 5)
    >
```

Answer (score 3):

At the `(= nth 1)` condition, you skipped the element but did not reset the `nth` back up to 5 (or whatever the initial value was). That means it stayed at 1 and skipped every element afterwards.

To solve this, you will need an inner function that keeps a counter, while still letting you hold on to the initial `n`. Here's my solution (I chose to count up to `n` rather than down from `n`):

```
(define (ndelete lst n)
  (let recur ((i 1)
              (rest lst))
    (cond ((null? rest) '())
          ((= i n) (recur 1 (cdr rest)))
          (else (cons (car rest) (recur (+ i 1) (cdr rest)))))))
```